# how to return a single item by its id in web matrix?

Tags: razor, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

How can I query the database using Web Matrix to get a single item by passing the ID in from another page?

Note: I'm using partial pages for alot of my UI, these are just pages in webmatrix, using:
 `@RenderPage("/page_name.cshtml")`

I'm trying to compose a `<ul>` from two tables and pages. A Services table which has an associated ServiceFeatures table. It WebMatrix it picks up the relationship by assigning a serviceID to the ServieFeatures table, that is the ServieId of the Services table.

So I have two pages to render the `<ul>` one **_ServiceList.cshtml** which has the following:

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("winmodb");
var servicesSql = "SELECT * FROM Services WHERE Featured = 'true'";
var services = db.Query(servicesSql);
```

}

```
<div id="service-list">
@foreach(var service in services) {        
    <h2>@service.Name</h2>
    <ul>
        @RenderPage("~/shared/_ServiceFeature.cshtml", @serviceId);
    </ul>
}
```

And inside of **_ServiceFeature.cshtml** I have the following.

```
   @{
   var db = Database.Open("database");        
   var serviceFeatureSql = "SELECT * FROM ServiceFeatures WHERE ServiceId = @0";       
   var serviceFeature = db.QuerySingle(serviceFeatureSql, serviceId);    
}

<li>@serviceFeature.Name</li>
```

But it's not working, and I'm not sure if I have to pass a variable or not.
I know that serviceId dosen't exist in the current context, this is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the _ServiceList page, your RenderPage call should look like this:

```
@RenderPage("~/shared/_ServiceFeature.cshtml", service.serviceId)
```

In _ServiceFeature, you can obtain the value of the serviceId using Page[0]:

```
db.QuerySingle(serviceFeatureSql, Page[0]);
```

Comment: You don't need an `@` in the call.

Comment: Yes, it does; it misleads people about the use of the `@`, which is confusing enough as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are passed in the `PageData` (non-dynamic) or `Page` (dynamic) properties:

```
@RenderPage("~/shared/_ServiceFeature.cshtml", new { serviceId });
```

In the partial page, you can write

```
db.QuerySingle(serviceFeatureSql, Page.serviceId);
```

In order to access parameters by name, you need to pass then as an anonymous type.

Comment: I think you need a string indexer with PageData. Dynamic properties work with the shorthand 'Page' version.